# Populate the textbox value based on another textbox from database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i'm trying to populate textbox value based on another textbox but i cannot populate the the other textbox. i'm sharing my code please guide me with best solution

Action Method:

```
public JsonResult AgreementNo(string id)
{
    string no;
    string _str = id;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT top(1) num from loan where id=@str", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@str",id);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    no = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["num"].ToString();
    return Json(new
        {
         no = no
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Script:

```
 $("#BarrowerName").blur(function () {                    
 $.ajax({                      
 url: '@Url.Action("AgreementNo", "Home")',
 // url: '@Url.Action("AgreementNo", "Home")',
 dataType: "json",
 data: JSON.stringify({ id: $("#BarrowerName").val() }),
 type:"POST",
 async: false,
 contentType: 'application/json,charset=utf-8',
 sucess: function (data) {
 $("#AgreementNo").val(data.no)
 response(data);
}
});                           
});
```

It Throwing the error like:Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '' to data type int.

Comment: are you getting correct value in parameter "string id"? i think id should be int.

Comment: i got the textbox value in string id

Comment: what is type of id filed in database? if its int try cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@str",Convert.ToInt32(id));

Comment: I rectify the error but value is not coming to Another textbox

Comment: debug jquery and check whether you are getting correct value in data in jquery success block

Comment: I kept debugger on sucess but it not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67654/discussion-between-sandeep-and-meena).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your error is in this line:-

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@str",id);
```

Since you are trying to pass an integer value to `NVARCHAR` column, Please change your code like this:-

```
cmd.Parameters.Parameters.Add("@str",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = id;
```

Please read this:- [Can we stop using AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Now, once this is fixed, change your jQuery code from `sucess` to `success` and it should work!

Apart from this, use [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement to automatically dispose your valuables resources something like this:-

```
string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT top(1) num from loan where id=@str", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Parameters.Add("@str",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = id;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    no = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["num"].ToString();
    return Json(new
        {
         no = no
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I got Just repalce sucess to success

Comment: @meena - Yup just take care while working with JS as simple mistakes are error prone :)

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a `string` to `Parameters.AddWithValue` method, but `int` is expected. Convert `id` variable to `int`.

```
int intID = int.Parse(id);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT top(1) num from loan where id=@str", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@str", intID );
```

**EDIT**

Here is complete code you may copy/paste

```
public JsonResult AgreementNo(string id)
{
    string no;
    int intId = int.Parse(id);
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT top(1) num from loan where id=@str", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@str", intId);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    no = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["num"].ToString();
    return Json(new
        {
         no = no
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

But there is a better solution if you expect integer id in `AgreementNo(string id)` method.

Just change parameter type to `int`:

```
public JsonResult AgreementNo(int id)
```

Comment: Here Id is textbox value ie.,string

Comment: i want another textbox value is int

Comment: with my i got the Value in no but in another textbox value is not binding

Comment: <td>
                        <input type="text" id="AgreementSeries" name="AgreementSeries" style="width:50px" />
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="AgreementNo" name="AgreementNo" style="width:50px"  /></td>

Comment: ok, place `alert(data.no)` in ajax success handler and tell what is printed

Comment: You should monitor ajax calls in browser tools (press F12) like FireBug in firefox. There you will find out why your ajax call doesn't work. Also try adding [HttpPost] attribute to your `AgreementNo` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67656/discussion-between-meena-and-jessejames).